# How to set Unassigned Value to Option Set CRM 2015 using Script or Business Rule

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I have an Parent Option Set call "Conveyance Type" as per image : 
[image]

Default is nothing select. If user Select "Elevator" then I am going to show the following Option Set called : "Capacity" and it's look like this. 
[image]

So let say use select "2000 lbs" .  Then after user select "Escalator" from "Conveyance Type" so at that time from Business rule I am going to hide the "Capacity" option set.

And again I select "Elevator" from the "Conveyance Type" I am going to show "Capacity" option set.  But issue is I am geting last selected value.

I have try `Xrm.Page.Data.Entity.Attributes.Get("new_capacity").setValue(null);` Using JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've got your case wrong. Try

```
Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_capacity").setValue(null);
```

Note that `data`, `entity` and `attributes` are all lower-case. I tried this in a `CRM 2016 Online` instance and it worked for me.

Comment: It will only open option set and it will remain open untill unless i click on that ....

Comment: @ujjaval I don't know what you mean. Can you please update your question with a screenshot and more detail about you're trying to do?